# Plotly losing color by scatter-sliders plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to create a bubble chart that simulates a month-by-month calendar, each bubble is a day of the year and its color corresponds to an event of the day, however, there are events that only occur in a specific month. Example event E and H that only occur in the month of February. These specific events are not being graphed, only the events that occur in the month of January are graphed. I would like to know how to graph all the events without missing any.

Currently the dataframe is:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    
    'day': [
            6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,
            2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            1,
           ],
    
    'num_month':[
           1,1,
           1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
           1,
           2,2,2,2,2,2,
           2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
           2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
           2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
           2,
    ],
    
    'month':['2022-January','2022-January',
             '2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January',
             '2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January',
             '2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January',
             '2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January','2022-January',
             '2022-January',
             '2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February',
             '2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February',
             '2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February',
             '2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February','2022-February',
             '2022-February',
    ],

    'y': [50, 50,
          40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
          30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
          20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
          10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
          0, 
          50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
          40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
          30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
          20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
          10,
               ],
    
    'date': date_list,
    
    'color': [
              'A', 'B', 
              'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 
              'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 
              'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 
              'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C',
              'B',
              'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'E',
              'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A',
              'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'E',
              'E', 'E', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C',
              'H',
              ],
    
    'event': [
              'A', 'B', 
              'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 
              'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 
              'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 
              'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C',
              'B',
              'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'E',
              'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A',
              'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'E',
              'E', 'E', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C',
              'H',
              ],
    
    'size': [
           50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
           50,
    ]
    
})
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['month'] = data['month'].astype(str)
```

The desired output is:

[image]

I have tried:

```
fig = px.scatter(data, x='day', y='y', color='color', size='size', 
                 hover_data=['day', 'date', 'event', 'month'], 
                 title='Calendar',
                 labels = labels_en,
                 animation_frame="month", 
                #  animation_group="event",
                 )
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False, title=None)
fig.update_xaxes(
    tickvals=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    ticktext=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],
    )
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "Date: %{customdata[0]}",
        "Week day: %{x}",
        "Event: %{customdata[1]}",
        "Month: %{customdata[2]}"
        # "Month: %{customdata[3]}"
    ])
)
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus") 
# fig.update_layout(showlegend=False) 
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False, title=None,)
fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'})
fig.show()
```

but for the month of February I lose the colors of the events E, H.

[image]

that I must modify so that when I go from month to month the colors are not lost.

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: See the following from the plotly site: 'Animations are designed to work well when each row of input is present across all animation frames, and when categorical values mapped to symbol, color and facet are constant across frames. Animations may be misleading or inconsistent if these constraints are not met.'
https://plotly.com/python/animations/#current-animation-limitations-and-caveats